# Installation screen rendering

Tags: system-installation

I have an older HP tower that has been running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server for about three years.  Upgraded to a proper server (DELL Poweredge) and decided to re-purpose the tower.

Ran 16.04 install.  The installation options don't show.  In other words, where it says English for the installer language it's blank, you use the arrow keys to get to the next option and it goes blank, you can see English.  The selected item is white on white.

Fumbled through as best I could.

System came up tried to login, says password incorrect.  Big surprise as I couldn't see what I typed.

Tried to go back to Ubuntu 14.  Same problem.  Plugged in a different monitor.  Same.  Ran the install with a really simple username and password.  Managed to get in.

Tried to install Ubuntu desktop 16, and then 14.  I get the Ubuntu install screen, select Install Ubuntu, get a white screen with a mouse pointer.

Is there any way to fix this problem?  I was hoping to run some experiments, test some various packages, and the like but I can't find any way to change installer colors, it's picking white on white for the selected option in server, and white on white for everything on desktop.